# How to create dynamic view structure in mvc to implement modules in CMS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am building a CMS system, using MVC 4 .NET

The system has the following objects:

**Page Types**

- ID
- Name
- Layout - the URL to the layout file

**Pages**

- ID
- ParentID
- Content (and so on...)

**Modules**

- ID
- Name
- Type (type of the module such as image galler, contact page, FAQ etc)

**The question**

Currently i am struggling on how to implement the modules in every page.
I have built the application in kind that every page will have a content and a list of modules.

My problem is that the page layout must be know in advance. So i will know **WHERE** to render each module in the view.

**I thought about this solution: (the current solution i am using right now)**

Create a layout page for each page's type and associating types of modules to each page layout.

Now when user wants to add a new page he will have to pick a layout (page type) first with number of modules associated. The problems in that solution are:

- I need to build a layout to each type of page.
- The user can add only the modules which associated with the page layout (type).

**Second solution:**

The second solution i thought of is to create the layout dynamically based on the associated modules.
I like to add that i don't know how to implement it.

In that solution the user can add as many modules he likes. But i don't know how to define the page structure with the modules.

- What if the user didn't create a module? how it will affect the layout?
- How can i create a structure were the modules not come one after the
  other?

**Basically, there is a way to store the position of the module in the page, and in the view to render the module in that position.**

I know it should involve render partial view to each module, in a desire position.

If there is a way how the module object should look like?

Does my question clear enough?

Comment: I fully awear of sections and partial views, I even wrote it in the question. But in one page type a module can be in one place and in other page it could be in a different place. And something he won't exist..

Comment: I tired there and I was told to ask here..

Comment: O, I stand corrected. Leme check this with a clearer head when purim hangover passes.

Comment: No I am not on urgent time line, I am actually doing it for me. So I have the to explore for the best solution.

Comment: OK, I'm gona take a little time and think over best way to answer this. Shouldn't be more than a day

Comment: Thought more about your CMS application. I would have an easier time working this out if you could add sample wireframes.
consider implementing the first idea. Fixed Pages are easier, then we can re-factor with JQuery. You already know that layouts, sections, and partials will be involved. A couple wireframes would help. You probably already know that layouts can be assigned on the fly. We'll lean heavily on partials with child actions.